# MapServer symbology: how to draw a line inside polygons following the outline?

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

Is it possible to create a symbology in MapServer/Mapfiles that would draw a line following the outline of the polygon, inside the polygon? Example with a simple rectangle:

[image]

I can't find any info in the doc for this kind of symbology...

Comment: Did you try grouping a set of styles using different offsets

Comment: Yes, but I guess I cannot use offsets for different shapes and polygons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest hit is probably geomtransform-buffer https://mapserver.org/mapfile/geomtransform.html

Unfortunately it does not work for you because by the documentation

> GEOMTRANSFORM buffer returns the buffer of the original geometry. The
> result is always a polygon geometry.
>
> GEOMTRANSFORM (buffer ([shape], buffersize))
>
> Note Negative values for buffersize (setback) is not supported.

If your data comes from spatial database a workaround could be to duplicate the layer and use negative buffer in the SQL of the DATA line of the new LAYER.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the workaround duplicating the layer with ST_Buffer and a negative value. A bit cumbersome just for this but it works!